# Múltiplos validators no form

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou com os seguints codigos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a versão do angular.json assim:

```
"@angular/cli": "~6.0.0"
```

Ao tentar usar numa versão mais atual fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o angular cll assim:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
```

Gostaria de nessa versão mais recente, poder colocar múltiplos `Validators`.

Answer (score 1):

Basta inserir "," e adicionar novos validadores no array. Veja o exemplo:

`password: new FormControl('', [Validatots.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(10)]),`

E assim vai..

**Edit** Utilizando `updateOn`

```
new FormControl(null, {validators: Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(2500)]), updateOn: "blur"}),
```

Comment: E o updateOn, tamb´´em entraria no array?

Comment: Isso! na ação de update também porém você precisa passar o valor a serem validados como primeiro argumento do `FormControl`. Sugiro você criar um método somente para criação do form que aceite os valores padrão dos campos como argumento. Na [documentação](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) tem vários exemplos bem mastigadinhos de como validar os campos.

Comment: Como ficaria no array ['updateOn' : 'blur'] no array?

Comment: @adventistaam atualizei a resposta com um exemplo de uso de múltiplos validadores e  `updateOn`